# How to select all entries between two dates in postgres using field with type timestamptz

Tags: postgresql

Here is some example code - I believe it should be simple to do, and the following code is the same as snippets I found around the web/stackoverflow..

```
create table mydb (start timestamptz);
insert into mydb values ('2019-08-05 10:00:00');

select * from mydb where 'start' BETWEEN '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-30 00:00:00';

select * from mydb where 'start' BETWEEN '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-30';
```

Both queries return zero results, when I would expect the value I inserted into the db to show?

Here is a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11842/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'start'` is a string literal (constant), not a column reference. You query is comparing the string (varchar) value `'start'` with the string values `'2019-08-01 00:00:00'`

You can see for yourself if you run the following:

```
select 'start' BETWEEN '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-30 00:00:00';
```

You need to remove the single quotes around `'start'` to make that a column reference:

```
select * 
from the_table
where start BETWEEN '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-30 00:00:00';
```

This is a good example why providing constant values with the proper data type helps writing better statements. If you had used a real timestamp constant (rather than a string) Postgres would have refused to compare the values:

```
select 'start' BETWEEN timestamp '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2019-08-30 00:00:00'
```

results in an error.

---

Note that with timestamp values, it's usually better to avoid the BETWEEN operator. I guess your query should include rows on August 30th as well which your current query does not. It would better be written as:

```
where start >= timestamp '2019-08-01 00:00:00' 
  and start < timestamp '2019-09-01 00:00:00'
```